# Failure to Upgrade Jessie to Stretch

Tags: debian

I am running in a package issues when trying to complete. It seems gnupg and python-apt are preventing the dist-upgrade process from completing.

My sources file is:

```
deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security  stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security  stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

The errors we are seeing are:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnupg : Breaks: python-apt (<= 1.1.0~beta4) but 0.9.3.13 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

apt-get install gnupg

gnupg : Breaks: python-apt (<= 1.1.0~beta4) but 0.9.3.13 is to be installed

apt-get install python-apt

dpkg : Breaks: libapt-pkg5.0 (< 1.7~b) but 1.4.11 is to be installed
```

The system has been upgraded but a bunch of packages are held back. I assume due to these packages.

Does anyone have suggestions?

-- Updated --

I am narrowing it down to python-apt

```
 apt policy apt dpkg python-apt
apt:
  Installed: 2.1.10
  Candidate: 2.1.10
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.10 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4.11 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.4.10 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
dpkg:
  Installed: 1.20.5
  Candidate: 1.20.5
  Version table:
 *** 1.20.5 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.18.25 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
python-apt:
  Installed: 0.9.3.13
  Candidate: 1.4.3
  Version table:
     1.4.3 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.4.1 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.9.3.13 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

----
apt policy apt dpkg gnupg

apt:
  Installed: 2.1.10
  Candidate: 2.1.10
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.10 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4.11 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.4.10 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
dpkg:
  Installed: 1.20.5
  Candidate: 1.20.5
  Version table:
 *** 1.20.5 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.18.25 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
gnupg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1.18-8~deb9u4
  Version table:
     2.1.18-8~deb9u4 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     2.1.18-8~deb9u2 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

--- updated looking into python-apt

```
 apt-get install  python-apt

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapt-inst2.0 : Depends: libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.1~exp9) but it is not installable
 python-apt : Depends: libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.4~beta3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


apt-get install  libapt-pkg5.0

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cron : Depends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libpam-runtime (>= 1.0.1-11) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: default-mta or
                    mail-transport-agent
 dpkg : Breaks: libapt-pkg5.0 (< 1.7~b) but 1.4.11 is to be installed
 fontconfig : Depends: fontconfig-config but it is not going to be installed
 init-system-helpers : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.20.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
 libfontconfig1 : Depends: fontconfig-config (>= 2.11.0-6.7) but it is not going to be installed
 libgssapi-krb5-2 : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.17-10) but it is not going to be installed
 librsvg2-common : Depends: librsvg2-2 (= 2.40.21-0+deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libssl1.0.2 : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                        debconf-2.0
 libuuid1 : Depends: passwd but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: uuid-runtime but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: What things do you have that depend on python-apt, and could you just temporarily uninstall it? Are there any unofficial repositories configured in sources.list.d/*.list? Anything "pinned" in apt/preferences? And... hopefully you are not trying to upgrade a server all the way from jessie to bullseye?

Comment: I checked for pinned packages. No packages held. I am upgrading Jesse to Stretch.

Nothing is in preferences or pinned.

I have narrowed it down to tow packages. 

libpod-readme-perl
python-apt

Comment: dpkg -l | grep "^hi" 

shows nothing listed.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to  libapt-pkg5.0

Comment: What does `apt policy apt dpkg gnupg` show?

Comment: i removed gnupg. that seems to then show other package dependency issues.

Comment: Your `dpkg` and `apt` packages are more recent than Stretch, that’s what’s causing issues (probably along with other packages in the same situation).

Comment: thanks. what i just did is i removed the python-apt package. hopefully its not needed. i think we used it for ansible as one point.

Comment: thanks for the help. i think what happened was, this i a system that has been steady been upgraded since Lenny o Etch. At one put I had to put testing into it to update spamassasin and they may have cause the conflicts. anywyas, just removing those packages seems to a have been an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

wound up completely removing the python-apt and gnupg packages.